# ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger problem while using Flutter's compute function

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm building an explorer using flutter getting apps length will take a while so i tried to get the value using annother **Isolate**, that's part of my main.dart code

```
Future<int> getValueFromIsolate() async {
 return await compute(
  apps,
  0,
 );
}

Future<int> apps(int n) async {
int value = 0;
List apps = await DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications(
 includeAppIcons: true,
 includeSystemApps: true,
 onlyAppsWithLaunchIntent: true,
 );
 print(apps.length);
 value = apps.length;
 print(value);
 return value;
}
```

And so there is my main function

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  getValueFromIsolate().then(
  (value) {
    print("Then the value is $value");
    },
  );
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => AppProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
         create: (_) => CategoryProvider(),
        ),
       ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => CoreProvider(),
     ),
   ],
   child: MyApp(),
  ),
 );
}
```

But i still got this error

> I/flutter ( 6234): ServicesBinding.defaultBinaryMessenger was accessed before the binding was initialized.
> I/flutter ( 6234): If you're running an application and need to access the binary messenger before `runApp()` has been called (for example, during plugin initialization), then you need to explicitly call the `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` first.
> I/flutter ( 6234): If you're running a test, you can call the `TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` as the first line in your test's `main()` method to initialize the binding.

I don't understand what it's happening
and i don't know what to do..!!
Please need your help Thanks for reading and your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Flutter platform channel has limitation - communications are only supported by the main isolate which created when your application launched.

1. DeviceApps.getInstalledApplications does invokes platform-channel to access platform API and
2. you invoke it from isolate - `compute()` creates new one for you

> However, there are two plugins to help you out:
>
> [flutter_isolate](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate) provides a
> replacement isolate that can communicate to plugins because it creates
> its own UI backing (nothing that you see or have to deal with, just
> technically),
>
> [isolate_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/isolate_handler) The
> advantage in using this package rather than flutter_isolate itself is
> that this adds handling capabilities, you can start several isolates,
> keep track of them and you don't have to set up your own communication
> between the isolate and the main thread (something you have to do
> manually with both the original stock Isolate and FlutterIsolate)
> because it's abstracted away and readily available.

If you still have quesdtion why? or interested to deep dive - [read all discussion with Flutter developers in github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13937)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again [Isolate Handler](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/isolate_handler#-example-tab-) solve my problem